# Get the count value of the column in the dataframe and set remaining rows as 1

Tags: python, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe with occ empty:

```
ID occ
a
a
b
a
b
c
```

Now I want to make another column that will count the number of occurence and only show the count in first row and rest should remain "1":

**expected result**

```
ID occ
a  3
a  1
b  2
a  1
b  1
c  1
```

In here 'a' is 3 times, 'b' is 2 times and 'c' is 1 times.
All other rows of a and b are to be shown 1.

I got the count by :

```
df['ID'].value_counts()
```

but it throws an error when I try to put it in a dataframe using:

```
df['occ']=df['Value'].value_counts()
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating `occ` column, assign value 1 as initial value and then you can use `pd.DataFrame.duplicated` passing parameter `keep='first'` to create the masking for first occurrence of the values, and assign the counts:

```py
df['occ']=1
df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first'), 'occ'] = df['ID'].value_counts().values
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
  ID  occ
0  a    3
1  a    1
2  b    2
3  a    1
4  b    1
5  c    1
```

**PS**: It may fail in scenario when first occurance of values in `ID` column are not in sorted form, you may want to sort `ID` column first in that scenario using `df.sort_values(by=['ID'], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)`, or you can assign the counts selectively comparing the values in `ID` column

Comment: i am getting the occ value but for 100 rows it is returning only 96 rows.

array([2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)

the 4 incremented only for starting rows but didn't put 1 for the remaining.

Comment: `2, 2, 2, 2` each counting `2` thus these 4 elements are equivalent to 8 elements, so `value_counts` seem to be working fine, just follow what I mentioned in the answer, it works fine

Comment: i know that but it should keep all other values to 1,
should i remove (keep='first') ?

Comment: Did you try assigning `df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first'), 'occ'] = df['ID'].value_counts().values` like this?

Comment: i am getting this error:
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: yes i tried it and then got this error

,I tried (keep = False) and still got the same.

Comment: Can you add the code you tried along with the error message in the comment?

Comment: **code**: df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first'), 'occ'] = df['ID'].value_counts().values

**ValueError**: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: when i do : 'df2['Value'].value_counts().values'

i get 96 values instead of 100, so this might be the area of issue

Comment: No, that's not the issue, since `df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first')]` will only have duplicate entries except for the first one, try passing the subset as well, `df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['ID']), 'occ'] = df['ID'].value_counts().values`

Comment: the alignment issue is still there, i tried sorting it but still its showing mismatch occ values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233563/discussion-between-dontaccept-and-anubhav-negi).